# Flutter : [Cloud_firestore] no data in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

when trying to get data from firestore in release mode "null" is always returned but not in debug or profile

#### Steps to reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. flutter run --release
2. no data comes at all from firebase

#### Expected behavior

as debug and profile it should get all data from firebase

#### Sample project

repository :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../../../domain/models/yearmodel.dart';
import '../../../domain/years/contracts/i.years.repository.dart';

class YearsRepository implements IYearsRepository {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static const String yearscollection = "years";

  @override
  Stream<YearsModel> get yearsStream {
    final docRef = _firestore.collection(yearscollection).doc("classes");
    final snapshots = docRef.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((current) {
      print(current.data());
      return YearsModel.fromJson(current.data()!);
    });
  }
}
```

ui with flutter hooks and riverpod :

```
years.when(
                    data: (years) {
                      print(years);
                      return Column(children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                          child: CupertinoPicker(
                            looping: true,
                            children: years.classes!
                                .map((e) => Center(
                                      child: Text(e.name!),
                                    ))
                                .toList(),
                            itemExtent: 46,
                            onSelectedItemChanged: (index) async {
                              isclinical.value =
                                  years.classes![index].isclinical!;
                              yearId.value = years.classes![index].id!;
                              yearName.value = years.classes![index].name!;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 210,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            yearName.value,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          )),
                        )
                      ]);
                    },
                    loading: () => const ShimmerAffect(height: 100, width: 100),
                    error: (error, stack) {
                      print("$error.toString");
                      Center(
                        child: Text("$error"),
                      );
```

---

### Additional context

### when the provider is triggered , it always hits the error: `(error, stack)` block

#### Flutter doctor

```
kivocsa99@kivocsa99:~$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.11.0-37-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

---

#### Flutter dependencies

````
~/AndroidStudioProjectsssd/mscmu$ flutter pub deps -- --style=compactDart SDK 2.14.3Flutter SDK 2.5.2mscmu 1.0.0+1
dependencies:
- android_path_provider 0.3.0 [flutter]
- audio_session 0.1.6+1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins rxdart meta]
- cached_network_image 3.1.0 [flutter flutter_cache_manager octo_image cached_network_image_platform_interface cached_network_image_web]
- carousel_slider 4.0.0 [flutter]
- cloud_firestore 2.5.3 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface cloud_firestore_web collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- cupertino_icons 1.0.3
- dartz 0.10.0
- expandable 5.0.1 [flutter]
- expandable_text 2.2.0 [flutter]
- file_picker 4.1.3 [flutter flutter_web_plugins flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle plugin_platform_interface ffi path]
- firebase_auth 3.1.3 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_auth_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- firebase_core 1.7.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_messaging 10.0.8 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web flutter meta]
- firebase_storage 10.0.5 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_storage_platform_interface firebase_storage_web flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection meta typed_data vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_downloader 1.7.0 [flutter]
- flutter_hooks 0.18.0 [flutter]
- flutter_slidable 0.6.0 [flutter]
- font_awesome_flutter 9.1.0 [flutter]
- form_field_validator 1.1.0 [flutter intl]
- freezed_annotation 0.14.3 [collection json_annotation meta]
- hooks_riverpod 0.14.0+5 [collection flutter flutter_hooks flutter_riverpod riverpod state_notifier]
- http 0.13.4 [async http_parser meta path]
- introduction_screen 2.1.0 [flutter dots_indicator]
- json_serializable 5.0.2 [analyzer build build_config collection json_annotation meta path source_gen source_helper]
- just_audio 0.9.12 [just_audio_platform_interface just_audio_web audio_session rxdart path path_provider async uuid crypto meta flutter]
- just_audio_libwinmedia 0.0.4 [flutter just_audio_platform_interface libwinmedia]
- logger 1.1.0
- motion_toast 1.5.0 [flutter]
- path_provider 2.0.5 [flutter path_provider_linux path_provider_macos path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- permission_handler 8.2.2 [flutter meta permission_handler_platform_interface]
- photo_view 0.13.0 [flutter]
- rxdart 0.27.2
- share 2.0.4 [meta mime flutter]
- shared_preferences 2.0.8 [flutter meta shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_macos shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- shimmer 2.0.0 [flutter]
- url_launcher 6.0.12 [flutter meta url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows]

dev dependencies:
- build_runner 2.1.4 [args async analyzer build build_config build_daemon build_resolvers build_runner_core code_builder collection crypto dart_style frontend_server_client glob graphs http_multi_server io js logging meta mime package_config path pool pub_semver pubspec_parse shelf shelf_web_socket stack_trace stream_transform timing watcher web_socket_channel yaml]
- flutter_lints 1.0.4 [lints]
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters charcode collection matcher meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph typed_data]
- freezed 0.14.5 [analyzer build build_config collection meta source_gen freezed_annotation]

transitive dependencies:
- _fe_analyzer_shared 28.0.0 [meta]
- analyzer 2.5.0 [_fe_analyzer_shared cli_util collection convert crypto glob meta package_config path pub_semver source_span watcher yaml]
- args 2.3.0
- async 2.8.1 [collection meta]
- boolean_selector 2.1.0 [source_span string_scanner]
- build 2.1.1 [analyzer async convert crypto glob logging meta path]
- build_config 1.0.0 [checked_yaml json_annotation path pubspec_parse yaml]
- build_daemon 3.0.1 [built_collection built_value http_multi_server logging path pool shelf shelf_web_socket stream_transform watcher web_socket_channel]
- build_resolvers 2.0.4 [analyzer async build crypto graphs logging path package_config pool pub_semver stream_transform yaml]
- build_runner_core 7.2.2 [async build build_config build_resolvers collection convert crypto glob graphs json_annotation logging meta path package_config pool timing watcher yaml]
- built_collection 5.1.1
- built_value 8.1.2 [built_collection collection fixnum meta]
- cached_network_image_platform_interface 1.0.0 [flutter flutter_cache_manager]
- cached_network_image_web 1.0.1 [flutter flutter_cache_manager cached_network_image_platform_interface]
- characters 1.1.0
- charcode 1.3.1
- checked_yaml 2.0.1 [json_annotation source_span yaml]
- cli_util 0.3.4 [meta path]
- clock 1.1.0
- cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.4.2 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- cloud_firestore_web 2.4.3 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface collection firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- code_builder 4.1.0 [built_collection built_value collection matcher meta]
- collection 1.15.0
- convert 3.0.1 [typed_data]
- crypto 3.0.1 [collection typed_data]
- dart_style 2.2.0 [analyzer args path pub_semver source_span]
- dots_indicator 2.0.0 [flutter]
- fake_async 1.2.0 [clock collection]
- ffi 1.1.2
- file 6.1.2 [meta path]
- firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.1.1 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_auth_web 3.1.2 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins http_parser intl js meta]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 4.0.1 [collection flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core_web 1.1.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 3.0.6 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 2.0.6 [firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.0.3 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_storage_web 3.0.3 [async firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_storage_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins http js meta]
- fixnum 1.0.0
- flutter_blurhash 0.6.0 [flutter meta pedantic]
- flutter_cache_manager 3.1.2 [clock collection file flutter http path path_provider pedantic rxdart sqflite uuid]
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.3 [flutter]
- flutter_riverpod 0.14.0+3 [collection flutter meta riverpod state_notifier]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter js characters collection meta typed_data vector_math]
- frontend_server_client 2.1.2 [async path]
- glob 2.0.2 [async collection file path string_scanner]
- graphs 2.1.0 [collection]
- http_multi_server 3.0.1 [async]
- http_parser 4.0.0 [charcode collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- intl 0.17.0 [clock path]
- io 1.0.3 [meta path string_scanner]
- js 0.6.3
- json_annotation 4.1.0 [meta]
- just_audio_platform_interface 4.0.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- just_audio_web 0.4.2 [just_audio_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- libwinmedia 0.0.7 [ffi path]
- lints 1.0.1
- logging 1.0.2
- matcher 0.12.10 [stack_trace]
- meta 1.7.0
- mime 1.0.0
- octo_image 1.0.0+1 [flutter flutter_blurhash]
- package_config 2.0.2 [path]
- path 1.8.0
- path_provider_linux 2.1.0 [flutter path path_provider_platform_interface xdg_directories]
- path_provider_macos 2.0.2 [flutter]
- path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter meta platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 2.0.3 [ffi flutter meta path path_provider_platform_interface win32]
- pedantic 1.11.1
- permission_handler_platform_interface 3.7.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- platform 3.0.2
- plugin_platform_interface 2.0.2 [meta]
- pool 1.5.0 [async stack_trace]
- process 4.2.3 [file path platform]
- pub_semver 2.1.0 [collection meta]
- pubspec_parse 1.1.0 [checked_yaml collection json_annotation pub_semver yaml]
- riverpod 0.14.0+3 [collection freezed_annotation meta state_notifier]
- shared_preferences_linux 2.0.2 [file meta flutter path path_provider_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_macos 2.0.2 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.0.0 [flutter]
- shared_preferences_web 2.0.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_windows 2.0.2 [flutter file meta path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shelf 1.2.0 [async collection http_parser path stack_trace stream_channel]
- shelf_web_socket 1.0.1 [shelf stream_channel web_socket_channel]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- source_gen 1.1.1 [analyzer async build dart_style glob meta path source_span yaml]
- source_helper 1.3.0 [analyzer collection source_gen]
- source_span 1.8.1 [collection path term_glyph]
- sqflite 2.0.0+4 [flutter sqflite_common path]
- sqflite_common 2.0.1+1 [synchronized path meta]
- stack_trace 1.10.0 [path]
- state_notifier 0.7.1 [meta]
- stream_channel 2.1.0 [async]
- stream_transform 2.0.0
- string_scanner 1.1.0 [charcode source_span]
- synchronized 3.0.0
- term_glyph 1.2.0
- test_api 0.4.2 [async boolean_selector collection meta source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- timing 1.0.0 [json_annotation]
- typed_data 1.3.0 [collection]
- url_launcher_linux 2.0.2 [flutter]
- url_launcher_macos 2.0.2 [flutter]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.0.4 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.0.4 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_windows 2.0.2 [flutter]
- uuid 3.0.5 [crypto]
- vector_math 2.1.0
- watcher 1.0.1 [async path]
- web_socket_channel 2.1.0 [async crypto stream_channel]
- win32 2.2.9 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 0.2.0 [meta path process]
- yaml 3.1.0 [collection source_span string_scanner]```

</details>

---
````

Comment: Did you fix it??

Answer (score 0):

You may not give permission to access the internet.

Go to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and insert this line in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

UPDATE:

Another reason may be that you did not give permission from Firestore.

For this, go to the project > Firestore > Rules

Then, modify the line which contains "allow"(mostly line 5) to:

`allow read, write;`

I hope that my answer will help you! :)

Comment: nah , that's not the case , i have added it to the android manifest file

Comment: Did you give permission from Firestore? I will update the answer properly to understand what you have to do.

Comment: yes i did everything , it's working on debug and profile mode as it should !